CORS issue with FastAPI despite using a specific middleware
I have a CORS issue with this code from localhost:3000.
I have checked the fastAPI documentation and add some code to tackle the issue.
But there is no change and I have always the error.
Here is my code :
import httpx
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

msgs=dict()

class Body(BaseModel):
    title: str

class Msg(BaseModel):
    type: str
    content: dict
@app.post("/posts/")
async def posts(body: Body):
    number= len(msgs)+1
    title = body
    msgs[number]= {
            "type": "PostCreated",
            "data": {
                "id": number,
                "title": title.title
            }
        }
    api_url = "http://localhost:4005/events"
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(api_url, json={
            "type": "PostCreated",
            "data": {
                number, title
            }
        })

    return msgs

@app.post("/events/")
async def event_monitoring(msg: Msg)  :
    print(msg.type)
@app.get("/posts/")
async def root():
    return  msgs

Here is the warning error :
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/posts/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

localhost:3000 is the client, localhost:4000 the server.
How to adresse this issue ?
EDIT : the server give this error :
"OPTIONS /posts HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed

all the methods are yet allowed...
EDIT 2 : This code works properly ! but I have now a 422 error.
import httpx
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

msgs=dict()

class Body(BaseModel):
    title: str

class Msg(BaseModel):
    type: str
    content: dict
@app.post("/posts/")
async def posts(body: Body):
    number= len(msgs)+1
    title = body
    msgs[number]= {
            "type": "PostCreated",
            "data": {
                "id": number,
                "title": title.title
            }
        }
    api_url = "http://localhost:4005/events/"
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(api_url, json={
            "type": "PostCreated",
            "data": {
                "id": number,
                "title": title.title
            }
        })

    return msgs

@app.post("/events/")
async def event_monitoring(msg: Msg)  :
    print(msg.type)
@app.get("/posts/")
async def root():
    return  msgs

EDIT 3 :
The class Msg was wrong...I had to put this and now it works :
class Msg(BaseModel):
    type: str
    data: dict


Have you tried with origins= ["http://localhost:4000"] instead? I guess you're using a front client from which requests are performed and it is running on http://localhost:4000

Thanks but same issue

Try from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
And does it work if you allow any origin?
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"])
If it does there might be some issue with the url passed to allow_origins.

Thanks but no change with the other import fastapi.middleware.cors that I have tried too. No change with ["*"] too.

With regard to the CORS error (which seems not being the issue anymore), please see this answer and the references included. As for the 422 Unprocessable entity error, the link in the banner should solve it for you. Finally, there is no need to use an HTTP client to make calls to endpoints from within your application, and if needed one, you should see this answer. Instead, you could call any endpoint directly as a function call, as explained here
